# Does TideSDK give you access to hardware (e.g. USB)?

Tags: usb, hardware, tidesdk

I need to do some basic talking to hardware over USB and am looking for a simple way to build a cross-platform desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Talking"? you can use the "Ti.Filesystem" from the tide API, it enables you to read and write files.

Comment: I mean access to USB port via libusb or pyusb API.

Comment: Ok, in that case you need to: 
1.)write your library(the pyusb, or libusb) like you mentioned(i personally would use phyton)

2.)Create a "Ti.Process" and listen to the pipe.
* you can also write to the pipe, and create a listener on the script itself.